# Apache POI Error When Using addMergedRegion

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am getting an Excel error when I use addMergedRegion.  Here is my code:

```
journalEntrySheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, 6));
```

The error I get in Excel says that the downloaded file has "unreadable content" and asks if I want to recover the contents.  I click yes.

Excel then opens the file and a window says that it repaired or removed what was wrong and then it says:

```
Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part
Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part
```

Etc.  There's a lot of sheets.

I check those sheets for the cell I wanted merged, and it's merged exactly the way I want it.

So why is Excel giving me this error, and how do I fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid range? If you create a range like you want in Excel and read it back in Apache POI, what did Excel create it as?

Comment: Also, what version of Apache POI are you using, and if it isn't the latest version have you tried upgrading?

Comment: If I unzip the xlsx file, and check the sheets that are having cells merged, it says that it is merging cell A2 to G2, which is what I want.  But I'm still getting the error.

Comment: And if you do it with Apache POI and compare the output XML, how do the two differ?

Comment: I am also having the same problem, If I am not merging the cell and try to merge manually then also it gives error

Comment: Did you able to fix it ?, If yes can you share how ?